# How do I move engine back to line up motor mount bolts 06 Subaru outback

Tags: subaru, motor-mounts, outback

so I just replaced my valve cover gaskets due to them leaking pretty bad. To get them out (without removing engine) I had to unbolt the motor from mounts and jack the engine up a few inches to get clearance to pull the valve covers out.

Now that the job is done I cannot for the life of me get the bolts to go back into the mount holes. It’s like the engine moved forward 1 inch. I’ve tried pushing on motor and it won’t budge. I can’t really find anywhere that looks safe to pry without breaking anything.

I really could use someone help here. TIA

Comment: I fixed it. The dog bone was holding it up. ‍♂️ I feel like a dumby now because I should have known. It’s been many years sense I’ve wrenched on a Subaru. Once I unbolted the dog bone the engine fell straight back down into position and was as easy as that.